# Replace After Delete trigger by Instead of trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to ignore the deletion of employees that have a salary higher than 5000. I'm using an `after delete` trigger on the `Employee` table. If the employee deleted has a salary higher 5000, it reinserts the row into the `Employee` table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER T1 ON Employee 
AFTER DELETE
AS
    INSERT INTO Employee
        SELECT * 
        FROM DELETED D
        WHERE D.salary > 5000
```

Is there any way of doing this without reinserting the row? How can I use  `INSTEAD OF` trigger in place of `AFTER DELETE`?

Comment: why not just raise an error if user trying to delete such record ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An INSTEAD OF trigger can decide what to do instead of facing changed records as with an AFTER trigger. This is mostly used for views that are based on multiple tables and that need to be updateable. The trigger then has to direct the updates to the correct underlying tables.

In your case, you would do

```
CREATE TRIGGER T1 ON Employee INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
  DELETE FROM Employee
  FROM Employee e
    INNER JOIN deleted d ON e.EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID
  WHERE e.salary <= 5000
```

Make sure that recursive triggers are disabled.